# My login form only reloads the page but doesn't log the user in

Tags: laravel

My login form is broken after I took out the "email" and "name" from the form, took out "email" and "name" from protected fillable in User.php. I also made the redundant fields nullable in the database. The user should be able to login using their "username" and "password". The registration form works fine, its just the login form that is causing issue.

login.blade.php
    @extends('layouts.app')

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autocomplete="username" autofocus>

                            @error('username')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                            @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                    {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Login') }}
                            </button>

                            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The model User.php

```
namespace App;



use App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;



class User extends Authenticatable

{

use Notifiable;


protected $fillable = [

    'username', 'password',

];





protected $hidden = [

    'password', 'remember_token',

];

protected $casts = [

    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',

];



protected static function boot()

{

    parent::boot();



    static::created(function ($user) {

        $user->profile()->create([

            'title' => $user->username,

        ]);




    });

}



public function posts()

{

    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

}



public function following()

{

    return $this->belongsToMany(Profile::class);

}



public function profile()

{

    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);

}





public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

}
```

The database table

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    }


public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
}
```

Comment: you have to provide codes for get any answer.

Comment: @hasan05 I just did

Comment: This `User.php` is model. your controller is on `App\Http\Controller\Auth\LoginController.php.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to `App\Http\Controller\Auth\LoginController.php`.

It will change your login field `email` to `username`. which will solve your problem for now.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

One suggestion for you. have a look on "how to use authentication of a framework."